# Condition in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have two string arrays and I want to iterate through one of them depends on condition. How can I avoid code duplication? Now `*ngIf` for now:

```
<tr *ngIf="!condition">
    <td *ngFor="let field of firstArray">{{field}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="condition">
    <td *ngFor="let field of secondArray">{{field}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let field of (condition ? secondArray : firstArray)">{{field}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hehe, I thought about this way. I've had to try! Anyway, thank you. That's exactly what I need.